# Input Validation to be a string and exception

Tags: python, string, list, validation, input

```
x = input("Enter state 1")
y = input("Enter state 2")
z = input("Enter state 3")

# The three states are strings among a list

For example:
    state_1 = ['Light', 'Medium', 'Heavy']
    state_2 = ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
    state_3 = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Black']

If x != 'Light' or 'Medium' or 'Heavy':
    print("Wrong input")
else:
    x = pre_defined_function(x) #let's say

# Same to be done with other states, output given only if all three states are entered correctly
```

I have tried doing try and except, but couldn't get it:

Please help me in identifying the correct method for this validation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \`a == b or c or d\` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: You are only doing a comparison of x against 'Light'. You have to check to see if x matches any of the strings in `state_1` Also, it is better to store your state list in a `set()` if you are only using it to compare your `x` string against.

Comment: @Karl The OP doesn't compare anything, the condition always evaluates to `True`, see the duplicate.

Comment: Perfect, got it...thanks people

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the comparsion statement `if x != 'Light' or 'Medium' or 'Heavy':` which actually is only doing a check for `x != 'Light'` and then whether or not the string `'Medium'` or `'Heavy'` are true (which they will because strings greater then length 0 evaluate to `True`).

An easy way to check if a string matches any value from a list of strings, is to use `set()`. Since a set allows almost instant lookup time to see if a value is inside the set, instead of having to check `x` against every value.

Using a set to check if `x` matches any of the strings in `state_1`:

```
x = input("Enter state 1")
y = input("Enter state 2")
z = input("Enter state 3")

# Store states in sets
state_1 = {'Light', 'Medium', 'Heavy'}
state_2 = {'Small', 'Medium', 'Large'}
state_3 = {'Blue', 'Red', 'Black'}

if x not in state_1:
    print("Wrong input")
else:
    x = pre_defined_function(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Karl provided a great explanation. Your if statement is only checking to see `if x != "Light"`. Since you're using `or` it will always pass as True because "Medium" and "Heavy" will always evaluate to True.

Something that may help out too is placing the statement in a while loop.

```
while x not in state_1:
    print("Wrong input")
    x = input("Enter state 1: ")
else:
    x = pre_defined_function(x)
```

this will loop continuously until valid input is entered.